# firefox error console showing warning?

Tags: javascript, html

firefox error console showing error that "error in parsing value for z-index. declaration dropped" i cant understand why this error is coming up. i have been trying to solve this problem for 3days but not getting solutions.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>error</title>



</head>

<body>
  <img alt="" src="/abc/images/icon_loading.gif" height="40" width="40"
                                    style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 20%; z-index: 9000;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there was this some firefox bug i heard just like this one....update the browser or else report this bug to firefox..

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that document. I suspect you have created a reduced test case that has reduced away whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: Looks Ok to me. Are you sure the error points to the same file and the same line (just click on the error)?

Answer (score 1):

The actual code (not the posted code, which works without warning on Firefox) probably contains a no-break space (U+00A0) instead of a normal space in the declaration `z-index: 9000;`. (At least such a construct triggers the warning.) Change it to a normal space. The problem might alternatively be the presence of an invisible control character in the code. Using e.g. the [BabelPad](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/software/babelpad.html) editor you can check out the exact characters, including controls, in the code.

Use the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check your code.